# How does Python do hostname lookup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, network-programming, hostname

I need to deploy an app developed in Python 3 to an environment where some requests need to go through a proxy doing packet forwarding. I have been told by the operations team that the correct thing for my app to do is to make HTTPS requests to a hostname, but resolve the hostname to a different IP address than the DNS servers provide.

When deployed in a Linux environment, what mechanisms does Python 3 use to resolve hostnames? Do some HTTP client libraries use different DNS resolution mechanisms?

(In case it’s relevant: the Python app is deployed in a Docker image, and the correct IP address will be provided as an env var to the Docker container at run-time.)

Comment: you need to edit `/etc/hosts` (on *nix) to include your desired mapping

Comment: You can also do the DNS resolution yourself in your application, using whatever nameserver you want.

Comment: Thank you @JoranBeasley, but what I’m looking for is the whole list of hostname lookup mechanisms used, preferably in the order they’re consulted.

Comment: this has nothing to do with python ... python uses your normal network/pc DNS resolution protocol